# HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/publicdata/queries?alt=json returned "Access Denied: Job publicdata:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

i'm getting the following error while trying to run a query on Bigquery using GAE python.

```
HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/publicdata/queries?alt=json returned "Access Denied: Job publicdata:job_c08d8f254c0449c2b3e26202e62ca5fa: RUN_QUERY_JOB">
```

Here is main.py code

```
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

# BigQuery API Settings
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'publicdata' # REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID

# Create a new API service for interacting with BigQuery
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
httpss = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=httpss)




class GetTableData(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    queryData = {'query':'SELECT word,count(word) AS count FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare GROUP BY word;',
             'timeoutMs':10000}

    queryData = bigquery_service.jobs()
    queryReply = queryData.query(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,body=queryData).execute()
    self.response.out.write(queryReply)



application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/queryTableData',GetTableData)
                                    ],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Here is App.yaml

```
application: bigquerymashup
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

i'm using App Engine Service Account for authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run a query under the 'publicdata' project (which is internal to BigQuery, and thus you don't have permission to access it). Queries must be run using the Project Number of the Google Developer project you created. See the [BigQuery REST API Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/hello_bigquery_api) page for more information.

One thing: your Class name in the example is "GetTableData" - not sure if you are trying to [List Tabledata](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list), or retrieve a [Table resource](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get)? In any case, here are some Python snippets that demonstrate how you might make these API calls using the [Google Python API client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/).

```
    def get_table(service, project_number, dataset_id, table_id):
      """Get Table information.

      Args:
        service: Authorized BigQuery API client.
        project_number: The current Project number.
        dataset_id: The name of the dataset.
        table_id: Id of the relevant table.
      """
      tables = service.tables()

      try:
        table_info = tables.get(projectId=project_number,
                                datasetId=dataset_id,
                                tableId=table_id).execute()
        print 'Table information:\n'
        print 'Table name: %s' % table_info['id']
        print 'Table creation time: %s' % table_info['creationTime']

      except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'Could not get Table information: %s' % error


def list_table_data(service, project_number, dataset_id, table_id):
  """Returns table data from a specific set of rows.

  Args:
    service: Authorized BigQuery API client.
    project_number: The current Project number.
    dataset_id: The name of the dataset.
    table_id: The name of the table.
  """

  try:
    table = service.tabledata()
    table_data = table.list(projectId=project_number,
                       datasetId=dataset_id,
                       tableId=table_id,
                       maxResults=10).execute(http)

    print 'Total Rows: %s' % table_data['totalRows']
    for row in table_data['rows']:
      data = []
      for values in row['f']:
        value = values['v'] if values['v'] is not None else ''
        data.append(value)
      print '  '.join(data)

  except HttpError, error:
    print 'Could not list Table data. %s' % error
```

Comment: replacing PROJECT_NUMBER = 'publicdata' with PROJECT_NUMBER = 'myProjectNumber' solved the issue. Thnks :)